# javascript inside the rendered page is NOT rendered in YII render partial

Tags: javascript, yii, renderpartial

I am trying to render a page as below from my controller

```
$this->renderPartial("_ReservationDetails",array('rowarray'=>$rowarray,'CalendarID'=>$CalendarID),false,true);
```

in my view file, _ReservationDetails I have the following content

```
....
...
<td>
     <button id="btnPrint" onclick="return PrintReciept();" class="btn btn-small" type="button">Print Reservation</button>
</td>
....
```

I wrote a script inside the _ReservationDetails as below

```
<script>
   public function PrintReciept()
   {
      alert("I am here!");
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

But when I click on `PrintReservation` button it throws an error in the console. `PrintReciept() is not defined`

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

In onClick attribute you state `onclick="PrintReciept();"`

Your function you'd better register thru [registerScript() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail):

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script', "
  function PrintReciept()
  {
     alert('I am here!');
     return false;
  }
", CClientScript::POS_END);
```

Comment: @Sachy, yes, in the view file. But might be also in the main layout file.

Comment: I am actually taking a break , I had been coding something else untill now, will start off again in an hour.. and will 100% let you know. I believe it should work!! Thank you!

Comment: This one worked for me >>> $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnPrint').click(function(){

     });

});